# Significance of 'this' keyword in start method

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm confused with use of keyword '`this`'. 
Case1:

```
sequence.start(get_sequencer, this);
```

Case2:

```
sequence.start(get_sequencer);
```

1. Both the cases are compiling without error. But case2 is giving is giving a violation in rules check stage.I want to know what difference does 'this' cause.
2. How 'this' is different from using it inside a function and while passing it as an argument.

Comment: Please show us your violation message.

Answer (score -1):

The `start()` method of a sequence has as its first two arguments:

- **sequencer** - a handle to the sequencer that sequence will start running on
- **parent_sequence** - an optional handle to the parent sequence that started this sequence

The Parent/child relationships of sequences are used in the locking/unlocking mechanisms among other things. The second argument it optional, so there must be some other tool that is generating a warning message that you need to explain.